# Binding a Dynamic Application.Resource WPF - User Control

Tags: wpf, dynamic, user-controls, resources

I have a custom class:

```
class CustomClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    CustomClass()
    {
        this.Test = "";
    }
}
```

I'm declaring this custom class on a Application.Resources like that:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:CustomClass x:Key="myobj"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

This resource is the DataContext of a grid  and the TextBox binds the Test property,  like that:

```
<Grid DataContext="{DynamicResource myobj}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Test, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>        
</Grid>
```

Suddenly at run-time, I change the value of the resource

```
this.Resources["myobj"] = new CustomClass() { Test = "12456" };
```

I want the value referenced on TextBox be always the value of the object that is currently on "myobj" resource, and I want change automatically the value of the current object when the value of Text property of the TextBox is changed, because of this, I used the Mode=TwoWay, but it's not happening.

I used WPF Inspector and I saw when the resource value is changed, binds a new cleared object and not my created object

I'm new in WPF sorry my english and my unknowledge;

Regards,

#### EDIT 1

It works implementing the code posted by ethicallogics, thanks! But sorry if I wasn't clear before, when binds a new resource as below

```
this.Resources["myobj"] = new instance;
```

it works fine when it is called inside the same window that this resource was declared, unlike when I call this line inside a UserControl, it seems that the UserControl doesn't inherit the MainWindow Resources, how that really works ?

Comment: More info needed. I normally don't apply binding in this manner so it perked my curiosity. I've created a sample project to try and reproduce your problem based on your provided code and the bindings update as expected. Please confirm that code sample you provided can reproduce your issue? Update your constructor to set the initial text value to "fred" and ensure that when the control first comes up it adopts that value. (Check for any binding error/warnings) What version of .Net/Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Vinicius Defeo - Your class does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, this can cause problems in the bindings ..

Comment: Yes, in cases where modifying the property in the object aren't being reflected in the bound textbox, however his example is that he's changing the binding reference to a new instance. (which should, and does work .. regardless of INotifyPropertyChanged) Though it does raise the question as to whether he's chasing this approach due to a lack of understanding INotifyPropertyChanged. (replacing the binding rather than updating the existing one.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    class CustomClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _test;
    public string Test 
    {
        get
        {
            return _test;
        }

        set
        {
            _test = value;
            Notify("Test");
        }
    }

    CustomClass()
    {
        this.Test = "";
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    private void Notify(string propName)
    { 
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName);
    }
}
```

Use this class .I hope this will help.